# How to launch another project from a different solution in Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have two VS solutions A and B and I want to launch A1 project from solution A from the project B1 from solution B.

Just so you know solution A has more than one project that can be launched. I tried to added A1 as a reference in project B1 but it didn't work so well and I'm getting some error.

Does anyone know what is the correct way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nor sure what you mean by "launch from B1".  If A1 is an executable then you could just execute it using `Process` methods.

Comment: If I need to pass some parameters when launching A1, can I do it with 'Process'?

Comment: If it's an executable and it takes command line parameters, then yes. Or do you just have a class in A1 that you want to use in B?  Note that the same project can be in multiple solutions.

Comment: Show your code/project

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your Solution A in solution explorer, go to Add and then click existing project. Locate the .csproj file for the project from Solution B. That project will then appear in Solution A. You can then set multiple start up projects to get it to run along side the Solution A project.

As a side note, using this method will cause the project from Solution B to build rather than just executing the last exe from the bin folder.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tried different ways mentioned in the forum and found the solutions:
- Add project A1 (.exe) as a reference to project B1.
- Make sure both projects use the same platform target (x86, x64 or any) since I got an error message because they were using different.
- Then call project A1 with constructor from B1.

It might seems confusing but I got it work without using Process because someone told me it would be more complicated to use Process.

Thanks for all your replies!